# SQL Application deployment Error to Device (Windows Phone 8.1)

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio-2010, windows-phone-8.1

I added SQL database to my windows phone 8.1 application and now I cant deploy my app to my lumia 520 or any windows devices, I need Help! The following is the error:-

**Error 1   The processor architecture of the project being built "Any CPU" is not supported by the referenced SDK "Microsoft.VCLibs, Version=12.0". Please consider changing the targeted processor architecture of your project (in Visual Studio this can be done through the Configuration Manager) to one of the architectures supported by the SDK: "x86, ARM".   MyProject.WindowsPhone**

Comment: The error message tells you **exactly** what the problem is, and **exactly** how to fix it. What else can we help you with?

Comment: Yes I did Try what the error tells me to do but no luck each time it gives me an error and tells me to shift to any other config

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out the issue there this is for any one facing the same issue, the Configuration of the project while adding any reference should be same as that you want to deploy too, SQL works on ARM and in my case the Config. was x86 to work on designer. it should have been ARM while adding the reference

Answer (score 0):

As the error says, switch **Any CPU** to **ARM** when deploying to device. You should always deploy ARM to device.

Comment: Yes I did Try what the error tells me to do but no luck each time it gives me an error and tells me to shift to any other config